# Does there exist such a $p$?

Tags: number-theory

> Does there exist an  $n \not \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$ where $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and is greater than $1$ such that there exists a prime $p >5$ such that \begin{cases}3^{n^2-1} &\equiv 1 \pmod{p}\\2^{n^2-1} &\equiv 1 \pmod{p}?\end{cases}

I tried finding such a prime but I couldn't. How should we think about it?

Comment: For all $n$, or for all sufficiently large $n$? For $n=2$ there is none.

Comment: @barto The question is correct now.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, moreover any prime $p>3$ can be obtained in this way: Given prime $p$, let $n$ be any positive integer congruent to $1$ or $-1$ modulo $p-1$. This way, $n$ can be chosen to not be $\equiv3\pmod4$.
We have $p-1\mid n^2-1$, and Fermat's Little Theorem does the job.

Answer (score 0):

Well by Fermats Little Theorem if $a^k \equiv  1 \mod p$ then all $b^k \equiv \mod p $ for $\gcd (b,p)=1$.

And $a^{p-1}\equiv 1 \mod p $.  And $p-1$ is lowest natural number that is so.

So all this is asking is does there exist $n $ and prime $p$ so that $n^2 - 1 =m(p-1) $.

$n^2-1 = (n+1)(n-1) =m(p-1) $ .

Let $p $ be any prime >5 .  If $p \equiv 3 \mod 4$ let $n= p-2 \equiv 1 \mod 4$.  Otherwise let $n=p \equiv 1 \mod 4$.

So phooey.  Let $p = 31$ let $n=29$

Then $2^{29^2 -1}\equiv 2^{30*28} \equiv (2^{30})^{28}\equiv 1 \mod 31$

Etc.